# Server to run java servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, servlets

I'am developing a java servlet application, and tesing it on Eclipse + Apache Tomcat (refer: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html#overview_wtp).

The application is now tested on the localhost and accesed by any clients on the same LAN.

Now, I need to deploy it into the web server, where everyone from anywhere can access this servlet.

Coud you guide me the way that I've to do to archive this task.

Comment: Your question is vague. Do you already have a webserver or not? Your question implies that you already have one (" **the** web server"). But the problem you're currently struggling with is totally unclear.

Comment: Nop, I personally don't have any web server (or I may have it now, but don't know how to implement it)

Comment: As far as things from a developer standpoint are concerned, you just need to create a WAR file for your application and you are done. What follows is mostly admin related stuff, namely, getting a provider for hosting your application which supports Web containers like Tomcat, Jetty etc., deciding whether your container would directly interact with clients or requests will be routed from the web server (e.g. ngix) to your container etc.

Comment: You don't implement a server; search for "servlet hosting" and you should get a fair idea of how things are done. For starters, you'll have to buy space/bandwidth from providers like http://www.MochaHost.com/BestJava

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a computer accessible to everyone - i.e. placed on the internet and not behind a firewall - with the appropriate software installed (and hardened against hacker attacks).

If you do not have such a computer, you can have a look at the Google Application Engine which allows you to deploy Java web applications (with some additional restrictions) to the Google cloud.  This is free for low-volume applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by deploying your application in the Cloud Instance. Since we cannot able to make our server instance or computer to be run always(We may come across internet connection problems, Power Fluctuation, etc.,), We have lot of problems while making our instance public(In Security perspective too). So it is better to use cloud instances.

We have many Cloud Service Providers such as AWS by Amazon, Google Cloud, Microsoft Cloud, etc.,

Take a look on this [List of Cloud Services Providers](http://talkincloud.com/talkin039-cloud-top-100-cloud-services-providers/top-100-cloud-services-providers-list-2013-ranked-0).(You have links for all top 10 providers)